# How do I get dates retrieved from external file to match dates in jq datepicker?

Tags: arrays, json, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

This is the first time I've asked for help, so apologies if I've got the format or level of detail wrong.
I want the datepicker dates to change their  background color for all dates that match a set of dates in an array of dates (highlight_dates). My code works with a manually entered array but NOT for programmatically entered dates.

**How I compare dates**

To check if a date is in the array I use ‘inArray’ (L11 in the following code):

```
1.  $('#calendar').datepicker({
2.  beforeShowDay: function(date){
3.   var month = date.getMonth()+1;
4.  var year = date.getFullYear();
5.   var day = date.getDate();
6.   // Change format of date
7.   var newdate = day+"-"+month+'-'+year;
8.  // Set tooltip text when mouse over date
9.  var tooltip_text = "Results available for " + newdate;
10. // Check date in Array
11.  if(jQuery.inArray(newdate, highlight_dates) != -1){
12. return [true, "highlight", tooltip_text ];    
13. }
14. return [true];
15. }
16. });
```

(L12 “highlight” calls CSS formatting)
This works OK when I use an array that I create manually (type in) as in:
var highlight_dates = ['10-9-2019','16-5-2019', etc];
All the dates that correspond to the dates in the array change their background color in datepicker - but when I use JSON to get the dates programatically (from an external directory) none of the datepicker dates change color.

**How I get the dates from an external directory**

I use the following code to get the dates from the directory (calling perl code as in in L4):

```
1.  function getResults() {
2.  $.ajax({
3.  type: 'POST',
4.  url: 'getResultsFilenames5.pl', 
5.  success: function(res) {
6.  //alert("reached L37  and JSON data is : " + res.result);
7.  //localStorage.setItem('dateArray', JSON.stringify(res.result));
8.  localStorage.setItem('dateArray', res.result);
9.  var resultDates = localStorage.getItem('dateArray')
10. //var resultDates = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dateArray'));
11. },
12. error: function() {alert("something didn't work!!");
13. }
14. });
15. }
```

The results are placed in localStorage (L8) so that they can be retrieved when needed.

**The results I'm getting**

When I display the dates (L6) - THE OUTPUT FROM res.result - they look like this:

```
23-05-2019,07-10-2019,20-06-2019,01-06-2019,30-05-2019,29-04-2019,,25-04-2019,03-10-2019,16-05-2019,,17-06-2019   (no square brackets or apostrophes).
```

However, with the addition of square brackets, and apostrophes in the perl code (which retrieves the dates) the array of dates  look exactly like the manual array when I display them using an ‘alert’ (L 6), so I think that the problem is not to do with the programming but more likely a formatting mismatch between the datepicker format and either the format returned by JSON or by the use of localStorage.

I’ve  tried using ‘stringify’ (L7) and ‘parse’ (L10) to change the date format but that  hasn’t had any effect. I’ve also (in desperation) tried changing the perl output to scalar (using ‘qq(@files’) – but again without getting the dates to highlight.

I don’t know what to do to solve the problem and I’d be grateful for any advice that you can offer.

Comment: Could you please show the output of `res.result`?

Comment: Reply to brandt.codes: the output from res.results looks like this: 23-05-2019,07-10-2019,20-06-2019,01-06-2019,30-05-2019,29-04-2019,,25-04-2019,03-10-2019,16-05-2019,,17-06-2019 (no square brackets or apostrophes)

Comment: Reply to brandt.codeswhen I add these - brackets/apostrophes -  in the perl code, the output looks just like the  manually entered array, but I still don't get any matches.

Answer (score 0):

You should transform the data to a valid array, then set it to resultDates and then store the data to the storage.

```
success: function(res) {
    var resultDates = getDataAsArray(res);
    localStorage.setItem('dateArray', resultDates);
},
```

and an small helper function:

```
function getDataAsArray(data) {
    return data.split(",");
}
```

Comment: Thanks v much for your reply brandt.com. 2 questions please;  first, does your function(res) transform the data to a valid array (or do I need to do this in perl code)? Second, where does the 'helper function' go in the code?

Comment: I meant does the helper function go in the perl code?

Comment: No, the helper function (`getDataAsArray`) is on the client side. directly under the `function getResults()` block. And yes, the output is a valid Array. Your problem was: you get a string from your perl backend. And the `spilt` method in `getDataAsArray` split this string into an array of strings.
When this solves your problem, feel free to mark this answer as valid.

Comment: I've added the 2 functions, but not getting the required result. Most likely because I don't understand a couple of things. First, what does (data) refer to in your helper function getDataAsArray(data) { ?   Second, I guess I have to call this function in the code with getDataAsArray() - is that right? Finally, does this mean that I don't need to call getResults()?

Comment: OK - I've added the 2 function calls: getResults(); and  getDataAsArray();. The result is that the array of dates now displays as: ['23-05-2019' (correct format, but only the first date element) and, second, the page doesn't display correctly. What might I be doing wrong??.

Comment: Ok. 'data' is a parameter. You pass it via `getDataAsArray(res)`.  Not sure what the other problem is. It seems to be another question. You should provide more code and maybe ask different specific questions. We can not guess what's wrong without code. The code above works with data you provided.

Comment: Apologies - bad choice of words on my part - your code works (many thanks) but the original problem remains: the dates in the array are not highlighting in the datepicker (whereas manually entered dates result in highlighting).

Comment: You are welcome. :-)  Feel free to ask more questions. And if a answer solves your problem, mark it as solved / valid answer.

Comment: Thanks. My question is 'how do I make the js code (which  is under the heading 'How I compare data' in my original question) work for the dates which are now correctly formatted?' Specifically, I don't understand why L11 of that code which uses the inArray construct works OK for manually entered dates but not for the programmatic dates . I'd be grateful for any advice/suggestions . Incidentally, can you let me know how to mark an answer solved/valid?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205856/discussion-between-brandt-codes-and-learner).